# How to run non-static code that uses dependency injection in .net core

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, console-application

I created a new console app in VS2017 and I am trying to run this code to demonstrate I can encrypt and decrypt strings in .NET Core. I have tried calling RunSample from the Program.cs Main but it wants it to be a static method. If I make RunSample static then I'm getting a null reference exception when trying to set the var protectedpayload.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection;

public class MyClass
{
    private readonly IDataProtector _protector;

    public MyClass(IDataProtectionProvider provider)
    {
        _protector = provider.CreateProtector("Contoso.MyClass.v1");
    }

    public void RunSample()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter input:");
        string input = Console.ReadLine();

        var protectedPayLoad = _protector.Protect(input);
        Console.WriteLine($"Protect returned: {protectedPayLoad}");

        var unprotectedPayLoad = _protector.Unprotect(protectedPayLoad);
        Console.WriteLine($"Unprotect returned: {unprotectedPayLoad}");
    }
}
```

How can I run it?

UPDATE:
Trying to run it from Program.cs, I have the following but `.MyClass` has a "cannot resolve" syntax error / red underline on it.

```
using System;

namespace encrypttest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            new Program().MyClass.RunSample();
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE 2:

I created my app by going to new project, .NET Core and then Console App (.NET Core):
[image]

UPDATE 3:
I've changed my code as suggested but have the following error:
[image]

UPDATE 4:
I've removed the using as suggested, but now I get:
[image]

Comment: You need an instance of the class to run it.  Show us how you are calling this from the main method

Comment: Where is the dependency injection here? I suspect you're not creating (or injecting) this class at all.

Comment: @DavidG how would I do this? Do I need a startup.cs?

Comment: @maccettura I've added the Program.cs code

Comment: OK, you don't have dependency injection here at all, why did you think you did?

Comment: @DavidG good question... I'm still getting my head around it. My code is from an article which talks about how this uses dependency injection right before the code is shown: https://greenmachinesec.com/2017/09/29/the-developers-guide-to-encryption-why-asp-net-core-2-gets-it-right/

Comment: That article is using ASP.NET Core, not a console application. If you want to run this code, you're going to have to do the same.

Comment: @DavidG I've added an image which shows how I created the project. What would you suggest?

Comment: Please use the Copy Details link on the exception popup to copy the relevant text of the exception. When others search for this post, they will not be able to find it because you're showing pictures of text rather than the text itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need DI your IDataProtector in Program.cs

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();

        services.AddScoped<IDataProtector>();
        services.AddScoped<MyClass>();

        using (var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider())
        {
            var service = serviceProvider.GetService<MyClass>();
            service.RunSample();
        }
    }
}
```

---

update - 1:

Install from NuGet

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
```

---

update - 2:

remove using like this

```
var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider()
var service = serviceProvider.GetService<MyClass>();
service.RunSample();
```

---

update - 3:

My code is DI example...
you need change like this

```
ServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();

services.AddDataProtection();
services.AddScoped<MyClass>();

var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
var service = serviceProvider.GetService<MyClass>();
service.RunSample();
```

Install from NuGet

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection
```

Comment: I'm missing a using for ServiceCollection?

Comment: Install-Package Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection

Comment: I've updated my question with the error this is now giving me. See the final image

Comment: remove using, because you MyClass not inherit IDisposable

Comment: OK, I've got another problem - see update to question.

Comment: see update3 and next time you must study google error message

Comment: I've tried googling my current error - ServiceCollection does not contain a definition for AddDataProtection - I'm not finding anything relevant from my search. So I'm sorry to ask for more help and thank you for your help so far.

Comment: AddDataProtection  -> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection

Comment: I had it but it wasn't working because I needed to remove other packages. It's good now thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The complaint about making `RunSamples` static is because you're not newing up the class that defines it. If it's not an instance, then the method must be static to access it. However, since the class (and method) has a dependency that needs to be satisfied, you cannot make it static. Simply, you need to use dependency injection to create an instance of your class with its dependency satisfied in order to call the `RunSamples` method.

To use dependency injection in a console app, it's as simple as adding the `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` NuGet package, and then:

```
var services = new ServiceCollection()
    .BuildServiceProvider();
```

However, that's not very useful as you haven't registered anything, so just do all that before calling `BuildServiceProvider`:

```
var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
    .AddDataProtection()
    .AddScoped<MyClass>()
    .BuildServiceProvider();
```

Since you want to utilize data protection, you'll obviously need the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection` NuGet as well.

Then, when you want an instance of `MyClass`:

```
using (var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope())
{
    var myClass = scope.GetRequiredService<MyClass>();
    myClass.RunSamples();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. My using of Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection is grey and saying it is not required by the code, however `.AddDataProtection` is underlined red.

Comment: "ServiceCollection does not contain a definition for AddDataProtection" is the error

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you are missing (from this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/using-data-protection?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // add data protection services
    var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
    serviceCollection.AddDataProtection();
    var services = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();

    // create an instance of MyClass using the service provider
    var instance = ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<MyClass>(services);
    instance.RunSample();
}
```

You have to initiate an instance of *IDataProtectionProvider* by calling *ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance*

Comment: ServiceCollection and ActivatorUtilities are underlined in red - what usings am I missing?

Comment: I added using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection; but now I get syntax error on `.AddDataProtection` - Sevice Collection does not contain a definition for it.